# how can use a wildcard in middle of a sub string that I dont know its length?

Tags: mysql, replace

I am trying to make an update on a DB replacing old characters for new ones, my problem is that at the middle of that string I have some characters I have to remove but I dont know the length or the type, I just know when the sub string starts and when it ends, for exmaple

```
my-string=XXXXXXXX-endstring
```

so, Id like to make it like this

```
new-string-endstring
```

I know my-string value, but dont know the sub string in the middle `XXXXX`

is there any way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Update fields which begin with `my-string-` AND end with `-endstring`:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column_name = 'new-string-endstring'
WHERE column_name LIKE 'my-string-%' 
  AND column_name LIKE '%-endstring';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use PHP you could do the following:

1) Make a `SELECT` of all rows that have the `my-string` text inside the column value

`SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name LIKE '%my-string%'`

- the `%` acts as a wildcard

2) Loop through all these result rows and use PHP's `str_replace` to replace `my-string` for `new_string`, and then use MySQL's `UPDATE` to update the new value of the column in the DB

Comment: hi, thanks, but how can i know the string that is between my-string and endstring? in the example: XXXX , i dont know the length, i thought about using the sub strings, but im not sure how...

Comment: If you want to filter out the text in between the known strings, have a look at PHP's `preg_match()` function. I'm not an expert on regular expressions, so maybe someone else can help here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SUBSTRING_INDEX to get the required string and use CONCAT to append new string.

```
Update TableA 
Set columnA = CONCAT( 'newstring' , SUBSTRING_INDEX(columnA, '-', -1) )
```

Comment: but , for example, is in your example columnA the string to replace? I want to replace columnA (i know the string) plus another short string that it could be a number of 3 or 4 or 5 digits until I find a " ... do you have and idea how to do this?

Comment: @jpganz18, columnA has a value like you mentioned XXXXXXXX-endstring.  i am searching for - from the end and retaining every thing upto - and concatenating the newstring to it.